# Unable to log into Cockpit server - could not set limit for 'nofile'

Tags: fedora, permissions, pam, ulimit

I have Cockpit installed on a Fedora 22 VPS that I use for educational purposes. I tried logging into Cockpit from my browser, but I was given a "Permission denied" message, despite using the correct password (it gives a different message for an incorrect password).

To figure out what was going on, I went to check systemd.

```
$ sudo systemctl status cockpit
● cockpit.service - Cockpit Web Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/cockpit.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2015-09-28 05:10:35 EDT; 5min ago
     Docs: man:cockpit-ws(8)
  Process: 1745 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/remotectl certificate --ensure --user=root --group=cockpit-ws (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1748 (cockpit-ws)
   CGroup: /system.slice/cockpit.service
           └─1748 /usr/libexec/cockpit-ws

Sep 28 05:16:04 myserver.com cockpit-session[1812]: pam_limits(cockpit:session): Could not set limit for 'nofile': Operation not permitted
Sep 28 05:16:04 myserver.com cockpit-ws[1748]: cockpit-session: couldn't open session: myuseraccount: Permission denied
```

This appears to be an issue with PAM, but I am unsure how to solve this or what the solution is. I wasn't sure if it was an issue with file limits (`ulimit -n` outputs to 100000). Any suggestions or tips?

Comment: Have you checked /etc/security/limits.conf
Most likely you have set a limit there and you don't have permissions set up correctly.

Comment: What about SELinux? I am not sure how is that handled in Fedora22.